# Shorthanded if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

While practicing for a ZEND exam, we run into the next question:

Outcome of this code:

```
$var =  true ? 'while' : true ? 'till' : 'false';
```

The answer is 'till'... 
But if you run it like this:

```
$var =  true ? 'while' : (true ? 'till' : 'false');
```

The outcome is 'while' as expected.

I don't understand why the first line returns 'till'. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The parentheses give it away. Without them, it runs as `$var = (true ? 'while' : true) ? 'till' : 'false';`. `'while'` is truthy so result is `'till'`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. Makes it all clear!